# Creating a dictionary of two-dimensional arrays in c#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create a dictionary of two-dimensional arrays in C#, I can't figure out the proper syntax.  I've tried the following to no avail, but it shows what I'm trying to accomplish.

```
    Dictionary dictLocOne = new Dictionary<String,double[][]>();
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A couple of things here:

Definition must match initialization. You are definining Dictionary and instantiating Dictionary<TKey, TValue>. What this means, based on what you are saying here:

```
Dictionary<string, double[][]> dict = new Dictionary<string, double[][]>();
```

I assume this is what you want. If so, your code might be something like this:

```
    double[] d1 = { 1.0, 2.0 };
    double[] d2 = { 3.0, 4.0 };
    double[] d3 = { 5.0, 6.0, 7.0 };

    double[][] dd1 = { d1 };
    double[][] dd2 = { d2, d3 };

    Dictionary<string, double[][]> dict = new Dictionary<string, double[][]>();
    dict.Add("dd1", dd1);
    dict.Add("dd2", dd2);
```

If that is it, your issue is solved.

Answer (score 8):

Just gonna update my answer to include the correct declaration as per other answers:

```
Dictionary<String,double[][]> = new Dictionary<String,double[][]>();
```

Alsoyours is a ***array of array*** and not a ***MultiDimensional*** one..Not sure if that's what you want..

If you want a MultiDimensional Array it's

```
Dictionary<String,double[,]> = new Dictionary<String,double[,]>();
```

Comment: Left hand side needs to be either var or Dictionary<String,double[,]>

Answer (score 4):

You also have to fully qualify the type of the variable, not only of what you are going to allocate:

```
Dictionary<String,double[][]> dictLocOne = new Dictionary<String,double[][]>();
```

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
var dict = new Dictionary<String, double[,]>();
```

Comment: -1, while this is correct, it really doesn't help answer the question. It just hides it from the developer, whom in this case doesn't know how to declare the variable.

Answer (score 1):

Example:

`var d = new Dictionary<string, double[,]>();`

d["foo"] = new[,] { { 0.1, 1.0 }, { 0.2, 2.0 }, { 0.3, 3.0 } };